# Varnish / Magento, Monitoring & Partial Cache Clears

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache, varnish, turpentine

As a admin user, I'm interested in monitoring the status of my site's cache.  Specifically, what's 'hot' in the cache and what's not.

The background is... I have a feeling that some of my admin activities are partially clearing the cache.

To specifically state the question:

- How do you monitor your website's cache? What tools and workflow?
- Does this method take note of partial and full cache clears?
- Feel free to add any insight into surprising things that clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Varnishstat and Varnishlog will give you all the information you require.

There are many plugins for Munin available that fully outline cache hits, purges/bans and ratios. Its very easier to monitor.

What's more difficult is getting the content into the cache in the first place (if you've got a low traffic, or large catalogue site).

If you are asking the question because speed is important, stop messing with Varnish and focus on making the site fast to begin with. Varnish is for sites that are already fast, not a bandaid for slow sites.

Comment: blaah not trolling but , show me a fast magento site :) it cries for bandaid and then show me a person who can make magento fast to begin with

Comment: Every Magento store is fast until people throw it on crap hosting, load it up with 3rd party modules and an off the shelf theme. If your out of the box Magento demo store isn't quick - then start by finding a decent hosting provider. If the demo store is quick but your store isn't - find a decent developer to profile your code, isolate the issue and fix it. I work with stores every day that load with caches off in under 0.5s.

Comment: your talk is too abstract :) put links and benchmarks to those sites you run in live without cache :)  or show me a dev who can profile magento codebase or take a random magento site and make it fly with all the crap that is installed . Isn't 3rd party extensions and themes meant to be used by merchants?

Comment: Its not abstract, take the default demo store with sample data as your base. I'm not here to self promote (and its not allowed within the rules of SE anyway), so I'm not going to list agencies or websites. I recommend you do your own testing and see for yourself. If you see more than 0.5s for a page with all caches off, change host, rinse and repeat until you find a competent Magento host that does deliver. Most providers have demo stores for exactly this reason. I profile at least 3 stores per week, with a guaranteed target for TTFB - and I always hit the target.

Comment: For your reference, no store I work on is live without caches, that would be madness - but every store is fast without caches. The caches just help make the hardware work less, but don't make the site any faster.

Comment: one link to competent magento host won't get you banned here and merchants aren't running demo stores :) however  if you can make decent progress with profiling you have a very large field of work :) and i hope your price is reachable for average merchant as well.

Comment: I'm not here to promote any single company (nor discredit any others), if your page load times are poor and you want to research different providers, then do so, use the demo store as your constant. I've given you the figures I would work within, so use those as your target. I've profiled several hundred stores and will continue to do so as long as bad developers exist ;) The price is what it is, for almost all it means a significant ROI.

Comment: that's definitely a interesting approach @serpyre, care to share more about the setup you are using? what about HHVM and all the custom extension code quality does that generate issues for you?

Comment: Anton, most Magento installations are slow due to incompetency. Very easy to blame software if you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose u are using magento ee with fpc active? fpc is much pain in this case. F.e. if you take a look at the cache tagging of fpc cache youll see that a specific page cache holds all cache tags from all rendered blocks on this page. So all pages with the menu are  tagged with all category tags of this menu block. If you save a category nearly the whole fpc will be invalidated. Monitor Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor::getRequestTags() to see which tags a specifig page cache owns. In one of our projects there are over 500 tags per page. Or f.e. if there is a static block rendered on a page this cache will be tagged with tag cms_block, now if you save any cms block youll also invalidate nealry the whole fpc. thats the reason why fpc is much pain and nearly useless.

regards

Comment: We are using magento ee and varnish.  RE: FPC. agreed. it's a pain. we couldn't get it to work right.